# geom_bar define border color of even column instead of all columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I want to draw a stacked bar plot using ggplot with blue outline on even columns. That is, making column 2, 4, 6, ... outlined in blue. However, I can only make it to outline all of them.

```
library(ggplot2)
test <- as.data.frame(cbind(a = c(1, 1, 2, 3), b = 1:4, c = as.character(1:4)))
ggplot(test) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = a, y = b, fill = c), stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(
    aes(x = a, y = b, group = a),
    colour = "blue", 
    stat = "summary", fun = sum,
    fill = "transparent"
  )
```

[image]

what I want to make:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach where you first choose the outline in the data. When you use `scale_color_identity()`, it will parse the color as provided in the `col` aesthetic, in this case `test$outline`, which is  `"blue"` if it is one of 2 or 4, or `%in% c(2,4)` to be precise.

```r
library(ggplot2)
test <- as.data.frame(cbind(a = c(1, 1, 2, 3), b = 1:4, c = as.character(1:4)))

test$outline = ifelse(test$a %in% c(2,4), "blue", NA)

ggplot(test) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = a, y = b, fill = c, col = outline), stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(
    aes(x = a, y = b, group = a),
    stat = "summary", fun = sum,
    fill = "transparent"
  ) +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>